# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (Python: Scraping from HTML data)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am trying to scrape the numbers from HTML data so that I can get the sum of them.  However, I am running into the above error when I try to run it.  It is referring to the "data = " line.  What is this error referring to in this line of code?  Have I set the "for" loop up correctly? Thank you for your thoughts.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tags = soup('span')
data = soup.findall("span", {"Comments":"Comments"})
numbers = [d.text for d in data]

summation = 0
for tag in tags:
    print tags
    y= tag.finall("span").text      
    summation = summation + int(y)                  
print summation
```

**This is what the HTML data looks like:**

```
<tr><td>Modu</td><td><span class="comments">90</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Kenzie</td><td><span class="comments">88</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Hubert</td><td><span class="comments">87</span></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no `findall()` method in `BeautifulSoup` - there is `find_all()`. Also, you are basically searching for elements having `Comments` attribute that has a `Comments` value:

```
soup.findall("span", {"Comments":"Comments"})
```

And, *this is Python*, you can sum up much easier with a [built-in `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Fixed version:

```
data = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "comments"})
print sum(int(d.text) for d in data)  # prints 2482
```

Comment: You are right; I meant to have that underscore find all method and use the built-in sum function.  I guess part of me is used to using "for" loops often.  Thank you for your feedback.